# Clustering data after linkage algorithm

Tags: matlab, statistics, hierarchical-clustering

I am not an expert in statistics and data analysis, hence I can't understand if the behavior which I obtain is correct or not. I am here looking for your help.

Assume I have these samples which I would like to cluster (10 points in the plane - reduced version of the problem):

```
 [X Y] =

266   450
266   400
258   168
290   442
295   438
273   432
294   158
318   161
250   423
253   413
```

To cluster them I can use a cluster tree

```
Z = linkage([ X Y ],'complete');
```

which is (by `dendrogram(Z,10)`)

[image]

Now I would like to extract clusters on the basis of the distance attached to the nodes of the tree.

Say that my distance is `150`, I would expect that the call

```
 T = cluster(Z,'Cutoff',150);
```

returns me `2` clusters. But it gives me just one (I suppose), i.e.

```
T =

 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inconsistent(Z,150)` and look at the values in column 4.  Increasing the cutoff from a small positive number steps you along the tree.

E.g.

```
cluster(Z,'cutoff',0.7)
```

does not give you what you want (I think)

but

```
cluster(Z,'cutoff',0.8)
```

does.

Answer (score 1):

The ***criterion*** for `cluster` is **inconsistency** (`'inconsistent'`) by default.

Since the height in `dendrogram` is **distance**, you can change the ***criterion*** to `'distance'`,
i.e:

```
T = cluster(Z, 'Cutoff', 150, 'criterion', 'distance');
```